# Camel Case y split o combine en JS, no entiendo que esta mal en mi codigo de transformación

Tags: javascript, array, string

En HackerRank tengo un problema que dice lo siguiente:

Tu tarea es escribir un programa que cree o separe los nombres de variables, metodos y clases en Camel Case.
Formato de Entrada:

- Cada linea de el archivo de entrada comenzara con una operación (S o C) seguido de un punto y coma, seguido de M, C, or V seguido de un punto y coma seguido de palabras que tu necesitas para operar.
- La operación será S (separar) o C (combinar).
- M indica método, C indica clase y V indica variable.
- En el caso de una operacion de separación (split operation), la palabra sera en camel case, sea método, clase o variable que tu necesitas separar en un espacio delimitado de lista de palabras empezando con lowercase letter.
- En caso de una operación de combinación, las palabras vana a estar separadas en la lista de palabras empezando con lowercase letters que ti necesitas combinar en un String de manera apropiada. Los métodos deben terminar con un set de paréntesis vacío para diferencialos de nombres de variables.

> (Perdón por la traducción, espero se entienda, todo en hackerrank está en ingles y no me gusta usar el google translate)

Los ejemplos que te dan y la salida esperada son estos:

- Entrada de Muestra:

S;M;plasticCup()
C;V;mobile phone
C;C;coffee machine
S;C;LargeSoftwareBook
C;M;white sheet of paper
S;V;pictureFrame

- Salida de Muestra:

plastic cup
mobilePhone
CoffeeMachine
large software book
whiteSheetOfPaper()
picture frame

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
var string = "S;M;plasticCup()\nC;V;mobile phone\nC;C;coffee machine\nS;C;LargeSoftwareBook\nC;M;white sheet of paper\nS;V;pictureFrame";

function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    var strToArray = input.split("\n");
    var arreglo1 = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < strToArray.length; i++){
        arreglo1 = strToArray[i];
        if(arreglo1[0] === "S"){
            if(arreglo1[2] === "M"){
                convertirSplit(arreglo1);
            }else if(arreglo1[2] === "C"){
                convertirSplit(arreglo1);
            }else if(arreglo1[2] === "V"){
                convertirSplit(arreglo1);
            }

        } else if(arreglo1[0] === "C"){
            arreglo1 = strToArray[i];
            if(arreglo1[2] === "M"){
                convertirCMetodo(arreglo1);
            }else if(arreglo1[2] === "C"){
                convertirCClase(arreglo1);
            }else if(arreglo1[2] === "V"){
                convertirCVariable(arreglo1);
            }
        }
    }

    
    function convertirSplit(arreglo){
        let inicio = 0;
        let arregloSM1 = arreglo.slice(4).replace(/[()]/g, '');
        let arregloSM2 = [];
        let arregloSM3 = [];

        for(let i = 0; i < arregloSM1.length; i++){
            if(arregloSM1[i] === arregloSM1[i].toUpperCase()){
                arregloSM2.push(arregloSM1.slice(inicio, i));
                inicio = i;
            }
        }
        arregloSM2.push(arregloSM1.slice(inicio));
        arregloSM2.forEach((palabra) => {
            arregloSM3.push(palabra.toLowerCase());
        });
        if(arregloSM3[0] === ''){
            arregloSM3.shift();
        }
        let strFinal = arregloSM3.join(" ");
        console.log(strFinal);
    }
    function convertirCMetodo(arreglo){
        let arreglo1CM = arreglo.slice(4);
        let strToArray = arreglo1CM.split(" ");
        let arreglo2CM = strToArray.map((palabra, indice) => {
            if(indice === 0){
                return palabra;
            } else {
                return palabra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palabra.slice(1);
            }

        })
        let arrayToStr = arreglo2CM.join("");
        console.log(arrayToStr+"()");
    }
    function convertirCClase(arreglo){
        let arreglo1CC = arreglo.slice(4);
        let strToArray = arreglo1CC.split(" ");
        let arreglo2CC = strToArray.map((palabra) => {
            return palabra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palabra.slice(1);
        })
        let arrayToStr = arreglo2CC.join("");
        console.log(arrayToStr);
    }
    function convertirCVariable(arreglo){
        let arreglo1CV = arreglo.slice(4);
        let strToArray = arreglo1CV.split(" ");
        let arreglo2CV = strToArray.map((palabra, indice) => {
            if(indice === 0){
                return palabra;
            } else {
                return palabra.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + palabra.slice(1);
            }

        })
        let arrayToStr = arreglo2CV.join("");
        console.log(arrayToStr);
    }      
}

processData(string);
```

Me dice que la respuesta es incorrecta, ya probe cambiar los console.log() por return no solo me idce resuesta incorreca sino que en la salida por consola me dice que no hay salida, no se porque persiste el problema

Comment: ¿Probaste ir concatenando todos los resultados en una variable hacer `return output;` en la función princial?

Comment: Si tu salida esperada es correcta no veo el error, trata de devolver un string entero con los resultados concatenados como tienes en ' salida de muestra' e imprimirlo fuera de las funciones

Comment: Hola Gabriel, creo que el problema, es que declaras **let arrayToStr** dentro de cada función anidada y le cargas el resultado, esta variable solo es visible dentro de la propia función, debes declararla fuera de ellas y en cada una usar algo como:  **strFinal += arregloSM3.join(" ") + "\n";**, luego solo te resta devolver **strFinal**.

Comment: Perdon por no responder, deje del lado este ejercicio, hoy al volver a retomarlo e intentar resolverlo probe con las ideas que me enviaron y no lo puedo solucionar. Los resultados deben ser devueltos me los pide por console.log(); . La salida sigue siendo correcta e intente juntarlo todo en un strFinal y luego mostrar dicha variable pero sigue presentando el mismo problema, seguire intentando. Gracias por las respuestas